# Phone Number Key Digit/Letter Permutations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation

I am doing some algorithm practice and came across a problem which I am having difficultly solving.

Each number key on a phone represents certain letters (e.g. `2 => A, B, C`, `3 => D, E, F`, etc. with the exception of `1` and `0`). The user can tap a key multiple times to "scroll" to a different letter. For example, `222` could be `AAA`, `AB`, `BA`, or `C`.

Given an input string such as `444223` what different combinations could this represent?

You can assume there is a dictionary/hashmap which has the number to letter mappings.

```
map = {
  2 => "ABC",
  3 => "DEF",
  4 => "GHI",
  5 => "JKL",
  6 => "MNO",
  7 => "PQRS",
  8 => "TUV",
  9 => "WXYZ",
}
```

I have attempted to solve this problem in two parts. First, split the input into an array of substrings of contiguous digits. For example: `["444", "22", "3"]`. Then, run each of those through a recursive algorithm which breaks the input down to its base-case (e.g. `f(4444) -> f(444) -> f(44) -> f(4)`) and then solves for the single digit and goes back up the chain working out all permutations.

However, I haven't been able to get this to work - and I don't know whether this is the right approach. I also had problems when the string of digits was greater than the number of letters (e.g. `4444`) as this could be two `B`s which I don't think would work with the permutation recursion algorithm I attempted to write.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are cycles allowed? e.g. can 22222 mean B?

Comment: That's an interesting case I didn't actually consider. To keep it simple let's say no for the moment, so either the user paused somewhere within that input (e.g. it's `CB`) or they are forced to pause if they press the key three times consecutively (i.e. it will output `C` if they like it or not). That said, I would be interested to know how to deal with cycles once I understand how to solve the more basic problem!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track breaking the streaks of identical digits into all their permutations.

The recursive part has up to three parts. So for 4444 the first step breaks into 3 pieces:

```
"4" (G) --> continue on 444
"44" (H) --> continue on 44
"444" (I) --> continue on 4
```

These continue on the remaining string, using the same rules.

EDIT:

This is a bit complicated to write in pseudo-code because of the data structure.  You need three things:

- The sets that contain each partitioning of the numbers
- The current set you are working on
- The value being worked on (such as "4" in the above example)
- The number of identical numbers left

So, for a given sequence of identical numbers, the partitioning works like this:

```
PartitionNums (sets, curset, val, len) {
    if len = 1 then
        insert into sets (curset, val)
    else if len = 2 then
        insert into sets (curset, val)
        insert into sets (curset, val||val)
    else if len = 3 then
        insert into sets (curset, val||val||val)
        ProcessSets(sets, (curset, val), val, len - 1)
        ProcessSets(sets, (curset, val||val), val, len - 2)
    else
        ProcessSets(sets, (curset, val), len - 1)
        ProcessSets(sets, (curset, val||val), len - 2)
        ProcessSets(sets, (curset, val||val||val), len - 3)
}
```

It would be called like:

```
ProcessSets({}, '', '4', 5)
```

For 44444.

This just handles one string of identical numbers.  This then has to be woven into code that splits the string and looks up the characters from the sequence of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, I figure the crucial part of the solution is writing a recursive function which takes a string of digits (e.g. `4444`) and works out the permutations. Being someone who finds these more advanced recursion scenarios challenging I don't quite follow how to implement your algorithm - does the breaking-up into 3 pieces happen as part of the recursive function, or does this happen first (in a wrapper function) and then those are fed into the recursive function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a cool problem so I wrote an implementation in Perl. The basic premise was split each set of digits into consecutive digits, then generate all possible groupings of those digits that equal the length of the digit string. After that simply feed the digits into a mapping table and group the results as a single solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use Set::Product::PP qw(product);

my %digit_map = (
   2 => [qw(A B C)],
   3 => [qw(D E F)],
   4 => [qw(G H I)],
   5 => [qw(J K L)],
   6 => [qw(M N O)],
   7 => [qw(P Q R S)],
   8 => [qw(T U V)],
   9 => [qw(W X Y Z)],
);

sub decode {
   my (@digits) = @_;

   my $last_digit = $digits[0];
   my @solutions;
   my @consecutive_digits;
   while ( my $digit = shift @digits ) {
      if ( $digit == $last_digit ) {
         push @consecutive_digits, $digit;
      }
      else {
         $last_digit = $digit;
         push @solutions, [ 
            map { _partitions_to_letter($_) } _partitions(@consecutive_digits) 
         ];
         @consecutive_digits = ( $digit );
      }
   }

   if ( @consecutive_digits ) {
      push @solutions, [ 
         map { _partitions_to_letter($_) } _partitions(@consecutive_digits) 
      ];
   }

   my @combined_solutions;
   # compute cartesian product of all partitioned consecutive digits
   product { push @combined_solutions, join '', @_ } @solutions;

   return @combined_solutions;
}

sub _partitions_to_letter {
   my ($partitions) = @_;

   return join '', map { $digit_map{ $_->[0] }->[ @$_ - 1 ] } @$partitions;
}

sub _partitions {
   my (@consecutive_digits) = @_;
   return [ [@consecutive_digits] ] if @consecutive_digits == 1;

   my @partitions = ( 
      # use the current array as a partition
      [ [@consecutive_digits]            ],  
      # each piece of the current array counts as a partition 
      [ map { [$_] } @consecutive_digits ], 
   );
   foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#consecutive_digits - 1) {
      push @partitions, [ 
         [@consecutive_digits[0..$i]],              
         [@consecutive_digits[$i+1..$#consecutive_digits]] 
      ];
   }

   return @partitions;
}

foreach my $solution ( decode(qw(4 4 4 2 2 3)) ) {
   print $solution, "\n";
}
#   IBD
#   IAAD
#   IAAD
#   GGGBD
#   GGGAAD
#   GGGAAD
#   GHBD
#   GHAAD
#   GHAAD
#   HGBD
#   HGAAD
#   HGAAD
```

Happy to explain any pieces that are difficult to understand.